# PHP preg_replace get only specific integer part

Tags: php, regex

I have set of static string set with different integer values. I am trying to get only the part I need using `preg_replace`. But the thing is whenever I get the number, it also returns the part after that aswell.

Example strings;

```
$str = "Increase weather temp by up to 10.";
$str2 = "Increase weather temp by up to 10abc 123 def.";
$str3 = "Increase weather temp by up to 10 12 14.";
```

Desired output for examples above;

```
10
```

My code;

```
preg_replace('/^Increase weather temp by up to (\d+)/', '$1', $str)
```

I also tried `~` but it didnt help me to solve the issue aswell. Whenever I test this regex through testers, it works [fine;](https://regex101.com/r/Dtj9II/1)

Is there any part I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex only matches the text (Increases weather...) closed by a number. So `preg_replace` replaces only this part with the first group. If you want to replace the whole string, even after the number, use

`preg_replace('/^Increases weather temp by up to (\d+)(.+?)/', '$1', $str)`

instead. The `(+.?)` causes the PHP to replace everything after your number too.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I already tried that before posting the question but in scenarios like `10a.` or `10abc.` it will not only print the integer but also print `rest - 1`

Comment: The lazy quantifier (`?`) and that second capture group are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "Increases weather temp by up to 10.";
$str2 = "Increase weather temp by up to 10abc 123 def.";
$str3 = "Increase weather temp by up to 10 12 14.";

preg_match("/\d+/", $str, $m);
var_dump($m[0]);

preg_match("/\d+/", $str2, $m2);
var_dump($m2[0]);

preg_match("/\d+/", $str3, $m3);
var_dump($m3[0]);
```

You can also use `preg_match` to get an array of matching strings and pick the respective element from that array.

Comment: Thank you @felix-g. I need to check the string before digit aswell. Is it possible to achieve with single `preg_match` or do I have to check the string first to see if it matches or not?

Answer (score 0):

True root cause of this is that you have different texts:

```
$str = "Increases weather temp by up to 10.";
$str2 = "Increase weather temp by up to 10abc 123 def.";
$str3 = "Increase weather temp by up to 10 12 14.";
```

"Increases", "Increase", "Increase" - the other two don't have 's' at the end.

and in `preg_replace`:

```
preg_replace('/^Increases weather temp by up to (\d+)/', '$1', $str)
```

Comment: That `s` was a typo, thanks for pointing out; fixed.

Comment: And with fixed typo your code works properly, although I would go with `preg_match` as Felix G suggested.